# Conditional Serializer Class In Request Method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am creating a single api for create or update. So if the auth user does not exist it will get created and if exists it will check for any update in the profile attributes. So I have used PATCH method where I can create as well as update. I want to create two serializer class one EmployeeCreate and another EmployeeUpdate. As the patch request would hold the request data I can find weather the user is already there or not and then I want to select the serializer class inside the PATCH method. I cannot even use the get_serializer_class(), as i have to define the serializer class before all methods.

In Views:

```
class AddEMPLOYEE(AllCreateErrorPatch, UpdateAPIView):

    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication, ]
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
    serializer_class = None

    def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self.get_serializer_class())
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        if not serializer.is_valid():
            return self.response_error(serializer.errors)

        req_data = serializer.validated_data
        if User.objects.filter(email=request.data['email']).count()==0:
            serializer_class = EmployeeCreate
            user_fields = ["email", "first_name", "last_name", "password"]

            user_data = {field: req_data[field] for field in user_fields}
            for field in user_fields:
                del req_data[field]

            user_serializer = UserSerializer(data=user_data)
            if not user_serializer.is_valid():
                return self.response_error(user_serializer.errors)
            user_serializer.save()

            req_data['user'] = user_serializer.data["id"]
         else:
            serilaizer_class = EmployeeUpdate

        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=User.objects.get(email=request.data['email']))
        user_profile_serializer = UserProfileSerializer(user_profile, data=req_data, partial=True)
        if not user_profile_serializer.is_valid():
            return self.response_error(user_profile_serializer.errors)

        user_profile_serializer.save()

        resp = user_profile_serializer.data
        # resp.update(user_serializer.data)
        del resp["user"]
        return Response(resp)
```

In Serializer

class EmployeeCreate(UserProfileSerializer, UserSerializer):

```
class Meta:
    model = UserProfile
    exclude = ("user", )
```

class EmployeeUpdate(UserProfileSerializer, UserSerializer):

```
class Meta:
    model = UserProfile
    fields = ("mobile",)
```

I want a technique through which we can do some sort of conditional selection of serializer inside request methods

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should not mix create and patch together, but if you have to:

```
class AddEMPLOYEE(AllCreateErrorPatch, UpdateAPIView):

    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication, ]
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
    # you do not need to define the serializer class

    def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        req_data = request.data
        email = req_data.get('email')

        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists(): # this is faster
            # do whatever on patch
            if EmployeeUpdate(data=req_data).is_valid():
                return # positive response
            return # negative response
         else:
            # do whatever on create
            if EmployeeCreate(data=req_data).is_valid():
                return # positive response
            return # negative response
```

Essentially, although it is **highly recommended**, you do not have to use django's own view presets such as `serializer class`. I would strongly advise against mixing the logic of a patch and create just for sanity, but it is technically doable.